# Remotely accessing OSX Lion from Windows in a sane manner

Tags: mac, remote-desktop, vnc, osx-lion

I have a 3-year old MacMini and 2-year old PC laptop residing on the same home 100Mb network.  To manage the Mac, I did the whole screen sharing thing (basically VNC) and I connect to it from Windows using UltraVnc viewer.

It is so awfully slow.  If I try to manage other Windows machines via either VNC or Remote Desktop, it feels so fast, you'd think I was actually sitting in front of that computer.  Meanwhile, I installed LogMeIn on the Mac and going through this app over the internet is sooooo much better and faster than local VNC.

At the moment the MacMini is running Snow Leopard and other than this issue I have no complaints.  I'd upgrade to Lion if I knew that slow Remote Desktop has been rectified.

Can someone tell me whether this issue has been fixed in Lion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't a solution with a speed of Remote Desktop on Windows, but the following [article](http://www.angryhacker.com/blog/archive/2011/09/10/sane-defaults-for-connecting-from-windows-to-mac-via-vnc.aspx) describes how to get the best experience possible.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Vine](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxvnc/) server on the Mac side and play around with the VNC settings.  I would also try a different VNC client on the Windows side.

I've had luck with [RealVNC Viewer](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/winvncviewer.html) and found that changing the encoding and color level in RealVNC helps to speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with macmini lion server - this sorted it after a reboot https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3289794 .

It's seems a bizarre set of instructions (on and off again) but it worked for me.