# Remote access on Lion

Tags: mac, remote-desktop, osx-lion, rds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remotely accessing a Mac from Windows in a sane manner](https://superuser.com/questions/273023/remotely-accessing-a-mac-from-windows-in-a-sane-manner)

A while ago I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/273023/remotely-accessing-a-mac-from-windows-in-a-sane-manner) about really poor user experience with accessing a Mac remotely from Windows.  It was horribly slow among other things.

Was any of this fixed in Lion?

Comment: There's no mention of right-click not working in that post *at all*. Consider updating your other question instead of just referencing it and asking "Is it still like this?"

Comment: @Daniel Beck.  I updated this question, since it has to do with Lion, rather than the previous version of the OS (e.g. the other question).

Comment: The other question is fairly recent, has no good answers, and doesn't mention a specific version of OS X. No reason not to edit that one to reference Lion instead. It'll be pushed to the front page again by that, so you don't lose attention on this site by doing that. Good luck.

Comment: @Daniel Beck.  Ok, other question edited.  Thanks.